# Using Polymer's firebase-collection to push a new document

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a problem understanding how to push a new document into firebase. I checked the documentation [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-collection) which refers to a method called add(data), however I don't really know how to use it (as my Polymer skills are still basic). Can somebody showcase how to push a new document by extending the sample element below.

```
<dom-module id="my-position">
  <template>
    <firebase-collection 
                        location="my-firebase-app.firebaseio.com/positions">
    </firebase-collection>

    <template > 
      <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{value}}"
      placeholder="Your name here...">
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: I'm not a polymer expert, but https://github.com/Polymer/firebase-element/blob/master/firebase-element.html#L101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use firebase-document and the data binding 'pushs' the object to firebase.

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-document

[Example](http://jsbin.com/lokegu/12/edit?html,output)

Comment: I checked the firebase-document implementation and there is no push method, there is only set and update. firebase-collection however has a method called add (which uses the push method of firebase). I don't think using firebase document is relevant in this case, or?

Comment: Is there a way to delegate creating the key to firebase? because in my example below the firebase-collection takes care of that, I just need to push the data.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very simple example that shows how to do it. It is based on the information given in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gErWcBdd-F8) (although using polymer 0.5, but concepts are very similar).

```
<dom-module id="my-elem">
  <template>
    <firebase-collection id="ref"
      location="https://my-firbase-app/positions/">
    </firebase-collection>

    <form id="createPosition">
      <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{name}}" type="" id="name" placeholder="name here...">
    </form>

    <paper-button on-click="submitPosition">submit</paper-button>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function () {
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-elem',
        computePositionObj: function(){
          return {
            name: this.name
          };
        },
        properties: {
          position: {
            type: Object,
            computed: 'computePositionObj(name)'
          },
          name: {
            type: String,
            value: '',
          }
        },
        submitPosition: function() {
          this.$.ref.add(this.position);
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an **object** to a location. (I keep a reference 'ref' for the next part)

```
      var ref = this.$.sparks.add(
        {
          content: 'Hello there',
          by: 'john'
        });
```

To add just a **key** to a location
have your collection

```
location="https://<app-name>.firebaseio.com/message/{{id}}"
```

When you want to add a key as a child simply do

```
this.id = ref.key();
this.$.COLLECTIONID.query.ref().set(true);
```